# Importing files in python project

Tags: python

I've skimmed over similar questions with importing problems, but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. This is my project structure:

```
root_dir
└── src
    ├── cyclegan
    │   ├── models
    │   │   └── cycle_gan.py
    │   └── utils.py
    └── train.py
```

I'm trying to run the `train.py` file like this:

```
python3 src/train.py
```

from the root directory of the project. But I have this error which I can't figure out:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "src/train.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cyclegan.models.cycle_gan import CycleGAN
  File "/home/ANT.AMAZON.COM/stefler/Documents/university/style-transfer/StyleTransfer/src/cyclegan/models/cycle_gan.py", line 7, in <module>
    from src.cyclegan.utils import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'src'
```

How should I import/run correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the parent directory name when you're importing from a sibling package:

```
root_dir
└── src
    ├── cyclegan
    │   ├── models
    │   │   └── cycle_gan.py
    │   └── utils.py
    └── train.py
```

inside `train.py`:

```py
from cyclegan.utils import *
```

Comment: It worked! Only the change is in `cycle_gan.py` and not in `train.py`.